# Do I have to initialize a std::string before I input it from stdin?

Tags: c++, input, initialization

I need to declare a new `string` variable in C++ and then read it from the standard input.

Do I have to initialize the string first, or is it an unnecessary step? In other words, which code is better: option 1 or option 2 (or are they the same)?

1)

```cpp
string s = ""; 
cin >> s;
```

2. 

```cpp
string s; 
cin >> s;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), it doesn't really matter. Since the default constructor of `std::string` initializes it with an empty string:

> Default constructor. Constructs empty string (zero size and unspecified capacity). ([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string))

Both lines essentially do the same thing in terms of behavior. It doesn't really matter whether you pick 1 or 2, but I would say that if the default constructor does the same thing, then the assignment is obsolete.

If you had some sort of an integral type, something without a default constructor, then most people still leave it uninitialized since the input is being taken right afterwards. However, I find it better to initialize such variables with a default value since this handles the case where input fails for some reason (Invalid type, bad stream state, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

For `std::string` default initialization is fine but with the use of (immediately invoked initializing) lambdas you can go one step further:

```cpp
std::string s = []() {
    std::string r;
    std::cin >> r;
    return r;
}(); //IIIL
```

This keeps to the rule "Always initialize your variables" and as a bonus allows you to declare the string as `const` if you need to and still be able to read it from a source:

```cpp
const std::string s = []() {
    std::string r;
    std::cin >> r;
    return r;
}(); //IIIL
```